# Value error while concatenating the numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, keras, concatenation, generative-adversarial-network

Im loading mnist dataset as follows,

```
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

However since I need to load and train my own dataset, I wrote the little script as follows which will give the exact train and test values

```
def load_train(path):
X_train = []
y_train = []
print('Read train images')
for j in range(10):
    files = glob(path + "*.jpeg")
    for fl in files:
        img = get_im(fl)
        print(fl)
        X_train.append(img)
        y_train.append(j)

return np.asarray(X_train), np.asarray(y_train)
```

the pertained model generates a numpy array of size (64, 28, 28, 1) while training. Im concatenating the image_batch from the generated image as follows,

```
    X = np.concatenate((image_batch, generated_images))
```

However im getting the following error,

> ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

img_batch is of size (64, 28, 28)
generated_images is of size (64, 28, 28, 1)

How do I expand the dimension of the `img_batch` in X_train so as to concatenate with generated_images? or is there any other ways to load the custom images in place of loadmnist?

Comment: `image_batch[..., np.newaxis]`?

Comment: i tried it. Im getting `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 163840 into shape (64,28,28,1) `

Comment: My data consists of series of subfolders with corresponding images. is there any other ways to load them as x_train and y_train?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a function in python called `np.expand_dims()` which can expand the dimension of any array along the axis provided in arguments. In your case use, `img_batch = np.expand_dims(img_batch, axis=3)`.

One other approach would be to use `reshape` function as suggested by @Ioannis Nasios. `img_batch = img_batch.reshape(64,28,28,1)`

Comment: is there any way to replicate 'mnist.load_data' for my custom data? My data consists of series of subfolders with corresponding images

Comment: it gives me an error as in `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 163840 into shape (64,28,28,1)`

Comment: Then it's probably because `img_batch` does not have shape `(64,28,28)` as you mentioned. Print the shape of `img_batch` and see what's the correct shape. You are using `for j in range(10):` so according to that your `img_batch` shape is probably `(10,128,128)` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
image_batch = image_batch.reshape(64, 28, 28, 1)
```

Comment: is there any way to replicate 'mnist.load_data' for my custom data? My data consists of series of subfolders with corresponding images

Comment: i tried it. im getting an error as `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 163840 into shape (64,28,28,1)
`

Comment: print image_batch.shape